# R packge submission to CRAN, pretest failure on Debian system: OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6891)

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I am submitting a package to CRAN, available on GitHub here: https://github.com/alexpate30/calibmsm

It passes all checks, including devtools::check_win_devel().

However, when submitting to CRAN, I get the following error when R is compiled by Debian: `OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6891).`

The error occurs after running all tests, which are shown to PASS.

```
[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 289 ]
  > 
  > proc.time()
     user  system elapsed 
  627.046   1.314 628.453 
  Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6891): temp_reg_status_file_name.
  OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6891).
```

The log is available here: https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/calibmsm_1.0.0_20231129_090516/Debian/00check.log

It’s difficult to make changes and test the issue, because the error only occurs when submitting to CRAN. I cannot recreate the error using any local tests, so any pointers to such tests would be useful.

I am at a complete loss, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring because the tests were taking too long. Adding skip_on_cran() to my longer tests solved the issue.